# QTP Calling Library function

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have same Function present in multiple Functional Library, when i call the function in driver script which function will be executed? for both multiple library and multiple function in same Functional Library.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function with the same name in multiple libraries, then which version will be executed depends on the order in which the libraries are associated to your QTP script.

If you have Library1.vbs and Library2.vbs associated in that order, the function within Library2.vbs will be executed as it will supercede the earlier loaded library.

Arguably you should never have the same function present in multiple libraries though as it can (and will) get confusing when you're trying to debug, maintain or improve your library code.

Comment: I would agree with that last statement...  If you have a situation where you have the same function in multiple libraries, then you should put some time/effort into fixing that situation.  Perhaps your libraries need to be redesigned.

Comment: @TrimbleEpic do you have any sources that have best practices in this area?

Comment: Most my my practices in this area come from careful thought about the nature of what a function library is...   However, I would love to point you to a book I love called Code Complete (http://cc2e.com/).  This book was really the first one that got me started thinking about how code -should- be designed.